# What are the consequences of "copying" a data set for OLS?

Tags: regression, least-squares, intuition

Suppose I have a random sample $\lbrace X_i, Y_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$. Assume this sample is such that the Gauss-Markov assumptions are satisfied such that I can construct an OLS estimator where

$$\hat{\beta}_1^{OLS} = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\text{Var(X)}}$$
$$\hat{\beta}_0^{OLS} = \bar{Y} - \bar{X} \hat{\beta}_1^{OLS}$$

Now suppose I take my data set and double it, meaning there is an exact copy for each of the $n$ $(X_i,Y_i)$ pairs.

## My Question

How does this affect my ability to use OLS? Is it still consistent and identified?

Comment: This is a linear transformation of the data, why don't you try seeing how this affects the estimator directly?

Comment: @JohnK It's difficult to conceive of this as a "linear transformation" when it actually introduces *additional data*!

Comment: @whuber Linear in the sense that $x_i \mapsto 2x_i$.

Comment: @Johnk The OP isn't doubling the values in the data set but stacking two copies of the same data set.

Comment: $x_i \mapsto (x_i,x_i)$ is still linear ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do you have a good reason to do the doubling (or duplication?) It doesn't make much statistical sense, but still it is interesting to see what happens algebraically.  In matrix form your linear model is 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}   
   Y = X \beta + E,
$$
the least square estimator is $\hat{\beta}_{\text{ols}} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y $  and the variance matrix is $ \V \hat{\beta}_{\text{ols}}= \sigma^2 (X^t X)^{-1} $.  "Doubling the data" means that $Y$ is replaced by $\begin{pmatrix} Y \\ Y  \end{pmatrix}$ and $X$ is replaced by  $\begin{pmatrix} X \\ X  \end{pmatrix}$. The ordinary least squares estimator then becomes 
$$
   \left(\begin{pmatrix}X \\ X \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} X \\ X \end{pmatrix} \right )^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} X \\ X  \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} Y \\ Y  \end{pmatrix}  =   \\
(x^T X + X^T X)^{-1} (X^T Y + X^T Y ) = (2 X^T X)^{-1} 2 X^T Y = \\
\hat{\beta}_{\text{ols}}
$$
so the calculated estimator doesn't change at all. But the calculated variance matrix becomes wrong: Using the same kind of algebra as above, we get the variance matrix $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(X^T X)^{-1}$, half of the correct value.  A consequence is that confidence intervals will shrink with a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

The reason is that we have calculated as if we still have iid data, which is untrue: the pair of doubled values obviously have a correlation equal to $1.0$.  If we take this into account and use weighted least squares correctly,  we will find the correct variance matrix.

From this, more consequences of the doubling will be easy to find as an exercise, for instance, the value of R-squared will not change.

Comment: And in fact, you can show that this is equivalent to a weighted least squares with weight 2 on each observation.

Comment: Surprisingly, there are areas of statistics in which there is (arguably) sometimes a reason to do this. It goes by the name "data cloning".

Comment: Interesting!  http://datacloning.org/dc.html

Comment: In Python, the $\sigma^2$ is estimated using $\hat{\sigma}^2$ which is computed using $\frac{1}{N - p - 1}$ factor rather than $\frac{1}{N}$, this actually makes the factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ slightly bigger.

Comment: It may be an obvious question. But after duplicating the data, say just add duplicate one row of $X$, then the new data matrix $X$ is not full rank, thus not invertible, and neither is $X^TX$. But how do we still have $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$? That will imply the solution is unique(but it is not because $X$ is not full rank)

Comment: @Gavin:  Adding new rows to a matrix cannnot reduce its rank!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I think I was confused by the terms $rank$. In this case, it means the column-rank. If $X$ is full column rank, then $X^TX$ is invertible. And I see your point, adding new rows does not change the column rank.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I think adding new rows will make $X$ rank-deficient (not full rank). Suppose $X \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 10}$ and $rank(X)=3$. Duplicating the last row of $X$ will make $X \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 10}$, but $rank(X)$ is still 3(so not rull rank) . However whether $X \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 10}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 10}$, it is $X^TX$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet familiar enough with the theory to give you a very mathematical answer, but intuitively, OLS only cares about proportions in which different cases are present. This makes sense when you recall that OLS chooses the coefficients that minimize the mean of the squared residuals, and the mean reflects purely the proportions of its inputs (in the sense that the mean of (1, 3, 3) is the same as the mean of a dataset with a million 1s and two million 3s). So, doubling the dataset will get you the identical model.

---

Here's an R example, where we generate a random regression problem and notice that the coefficients are unchanged when doubling the data:

```
nc = sample(1:10, 1, replace = T)
n = sample(11:500, 1, replace = T)
x = as.matrix(replicate(nc, rnorm(n)))
coef = rnorm(nc)
sd.resid = runif(1, 0, 5)

y = x %*% matrix(coef) + rnorm(n, sd = sd.resid)

print(cbind(
  coef(lm(y ~ x)),
  coef(lm(c(y, y) ~ rbind(x, x)))))
```

One run gives me:

```
                   [,1]        [,2]
(Intercept) -0.10002238 -0.10002238
x1          -2.14801619 -2.14801619
x2           0.23120764  0.23120764
x3           0.05360792  0.05360792
x4           1.91972198  1.91972198
x5          -1.09887264 -1.09887264
x6           0.04248358  0.04248358
```

Comment: As statisticians, we do far more than just estimate parameters.  At the least, we evaluate how uncertain they are.  Doubling the data will (typically and approximately) halve the variances, making the results look much more solid than they ought to.  This error has huge ramifications for interval estimation, such as confidence and prediction intervals. Another way to characterize the mistake is to recognize that each doubled pair of responses is perfectly correlated, so applying OLS to them as if they were independent uses the wrong error structure.

Comment: I agree, but to me, that is a matter of inferences about the model rather the model itself. Doing something like computing a confidence interval for a parameter is not part of OLS per se, even if the parameter comes from OLS.

Comment: Inference is impossible without information about the potential inaccuracy.  Otherwise, you have no valid response to the question "how sure are you of your answer?"  That is why (at a minimum) computing a variance-covariance matrix of the residuals is an essential part of OLS.  Anything less is just algorithmic curve fitting.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said *inferences* about the model. I would agree that OLS per se is a kind of algorithmic curve-fitting.

Comment: But I disagree with that.  To me, and to all the statistical textbooks and papers I have access to, OLS is much more than algorithmic curve fitting.

Comment: In that case, what does one call the procedure of computing the coefficients of a linear model such that the sum of the squared deviations is minimized?

Comment: It depends on the procedure.  Whatever it is, many people would call it an "algorithm."  Certainly in that case discussions of OLS would not focus on model specification such as homoscedasticity and independence of residuals, whereas they all do.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) *inter alia.*

Comment: @whuber I don't understand why the duplicating the data halves the variance of beta. Kjetil also made that statement above too. But when I derive it, I just get the same variance

\begin{align}
    var(\beta) = var(\left( [X^T \ \ X^T] \begin{bmatrix}X \\ X\end{bmatrix} \right)^{-1}[X^T \ \ X^T] \begin{bmatrix}
    Y \\
    Y
    \end{bmatrix}) \\
    = var(\left( 2X^TX \right)^{-1} 2X^TY) \\
    = var(\left(X^TX \right)^{-1}X^TY) \\
\end{align}

Comment: It seems they just plugged in $X = [X \ \ X]^T$ to the equation $var(\beta) = \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$. That makes sense and I see where the 0.5 factor comes from, but I don't get why my approach / thought process above is wrong

Comment: @Iamanon You calculate the variance as if the errors in $(Y,Y)^\prime$ were iid--but they are not: they come in perfectly correlated pairs.

Comment: @whuber Hmm could you expand on that because I don't see where the IID assumption was made in my above derivation? I just used linear algebra inside the $var(\cdot)$, and I don't think I made any assumptions to get to $var((X^TX)^{-1}X^TY).