# What is the consequence of "copying" a dataset for Ridge or Lasso?

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, lasso, ridge-regression

So I know that for OLS, "copying" each of the N observations $(X_i,Y_i)$ once to get a dataset of size 2N has no effect on the **values** of the coefficients in OLS ([related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216003/what-are-the-consequences-of-copying-a-data-set-for-ols)).

Does this still hold true for Ridge and Lasso regressions? I've ran experiments where the coefficients turns out do differ by a small amount. But I'm not sure if that's due to computation complications. Could someone please give a theoretical explanation why the coefficient would change (or why not?)

Comment: If you fix the penalty as some value, like 42, then no because the log-likelihood grows by a factor of log 2 when you "double" your dataset. You can probably choose a bigger penalty (multiply by log 2) to give you the same result. If you choose the penalty through some automated procedure, like cross-validation, to optimize the cross-validated R2, you'll still likely pick a smaller penalty less than log 2 times the original CVoptimal penalty.

Comment: @AdamO Thanks. I just worked through a 1-variable example for ridge, since ridge has a closed form solution. And it became clear that coefficient will stay the same IFF I double λ the penalty term

Comment: My [data augmentation characterization of Ridge Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919) gives useful insight. Indeed, if you were to copy the *augmented* values also, the ridge solution would be identical.  Since copying them is tantamount to doubling each value, the only change will be the cosmetic one of doubling the relaxation parameter.