Is duplicating dataset an augmentation?
For a very small dataset, there is a lot of overfit in the random forest regressor model.  I have removed extraneous data, scaling and feature selection, but overfit is still there.  The oversampling technique greatly improves the results, but because it does not create unrealistic data, I am not allowed to use this technique.  Can I double the data set (repeat the data twice) and improve the data set like this?  Or should I multiply the dataset by a number and add it to the main dataset?  Do you think these methods are reasonable and valid? Dataset is tabular and numeric.

Doubling (presumably, replicating each observation) cannot do anything to "improve" the dataset, so it would appear it is being proposed as part of a statistical procedure to analyze the data.  Consider instead, then, improving how you analyze the data.  Otherwise very subtle things can happen to deceive you.  Although https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216003 is not about random forests, it might give you a taste of what to expect.

Duplicating the dataset without changing anything is a bad idea. It does nothing useful (no augmentation is done, no new information added), but pollutes the out-of-bag (i.e. when you randomly sample records to train on vs. to assess fit, you now often end up with the same record in both training and out-of-bag). Even if you did some data augmentation (e.g. randomly changing features in various ways you believe would not change the outcome), you'd want to make sure to always keep these records together. I.e. always in train or out-of-bag together, and of course you must also respect this for train/(cross-)validation/test splits.

I don't think it's reasonable to duplicate existing data and call it data augmentation. Augmentation as I understand it involves some sort of transformation to the data (rotating images, adding noise, etc.). Multiplying all the duplicated values by some number would meet this very basic criterion, but I don't see how this could achieve anything useful in your case.
